# Delete XML element

Tags: c#, xml

I've got an XML file like this one:

```
<position>
    <Game> Batman Arkham City </Game>
    <Movie> Inception   </Movie>
    <Movie> Dark Knight </Movie>
    [etc...]
</position>
```

All I want is delete a single line in existing file, if `InnerText == TextBox`. For example: If I'll put a "Inception" text into text box and press button, than program will delete line with "Inception". How can I do that? I was trying many different ways. Very important for me is, I don't want change format of XML file, because I already have created a code to another options, like input items into listbox, or creating new title in current XML file.

Can you tell how can I do that?

---

**EDIT (from comment):** My last attempt to do this:

```
XmlDocument dok = new XmlDocument();
dok.Load("DataBase/list.xml");
foreach(XmlNode node in dok.SelectNodes("position"))
{
    if (node.SelectSingleNode("Game").InnerText == searchTxt.Text)
    {
        node.RemoveChild(node);
    }
}

dok.Save("DataBase/list.xml");
```

Comment: You need to delete that from 1 `position`, from all `position`s?

Comment: Google has so many threads for this..

Comment: Noctis: Yes, i dont want erease all of elements, just one. I dont know, what I am doing wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var element = XElement.Load(reader);

                var toBeRemovedElements = element.Elements().Where(e => e.Value == parameter).ToList();

                toBeRemovedElements.ForEach(e => e.Remove());
            }
```

Let me know if I've understood your question badly.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove node from node, that doesn;t work. Remove the node from its parent, dok.

```
XmlDocument dok = new XmlDocument();
dok.Load("DataBase/list.xml");
foreach(XmlNode node in dok.SelectNodes("position"))
{
    if (node.SelectSingleNode("Game").InnerText == searchTxt.Text)
    {
        dok.RemoveChild(node);
    }
}

dok.Save("DataBase/list.xml");
```